# What is the difference between libgtk2.0 and libgtk2.0-0 when using apt-get?

Tags: apt, gtk

It seems like for `gnu-smalltalk`, I will need `libgtk2.0`... but for some reason, it is not automatically installed when I used

```
sudo apt-get install gnu-smalltalk
```

(1) Is that a bug?

(2) When I searched for `libgtk2.0`

```
apt-cache search libgtk2.0
```

It listed a lot of things, but there is only one `libgtk2.0-0`

So I installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
```

but it installed nothing.  So `gst-browser`, which is GNU Smalltalk the GUI version, would not run.

Then I have to

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0
```

and it installed a ton of stuff, and one post said that `libcairo2` is needed too, so I installed it also:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2
```

and `gst-browser` would run.

What is the difference between `libgtk2.0` and `libgtk2.0-0` then?  Why did the line `apt-cache search libgtk2.0` not give any result called `libgtk2.0` also?

Comment: There is no `libgtk2.0`. By installing a package with `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0` you installed instead all the things with a similar name, thanks to the `.` in the name. Refer to [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/502895/29595) for more explanations on this.

Answer (score 0):

`-0` at the end means  that there was not a debian package yet. If it was `libgtk2.0-1` for example it would mean that this is the 1st debian package of version libgtk2.0

Doing a quick apt-cache when you `sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0` you only installed GTK+ graphical user interface library not everything else needed. When you `sudo apt-get installed libgtk2.0` it pulled in everything else needed thus why it now works.

Comment: `was not a debian package yet`, what? https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgtk2.0-0